# How should I store unused stickers?

Tags: storage, stickers

What is the best way to store stickers for future use? I have some unused LEGO sticker sets in plastic bags. The one on top in the bag has become brittle and is flaking.

Answer (score 13):

Think about what causes the stickers to deteriorate:

- Heat loosens the bonds in the glue, which results in stickers peeling.
- Exposure to natural light will cause the colours in the stickers to
  fade over time. Unlike LEGO bricks, stickers fade faster under natural light.

With those points in mind, keep stickers in a **cool, dry, place away from sunlight** like in a cupboard or drawer. Zip lock/food bags are also helpful for organising stickers which is why they can also be [used to store instructions and catalogues.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14BFI.jpg)

Stickers transferred from the sticker sheet onto other surfaces will also be affected by dust, oil and any other particles that will affect the lifespan of a sticker. Make sure the surface is clean and dry before applying stickers.

You can use a hairdryer to easily remove stickers from bricks.

Answer (score 8):

Another option may to be store them inbetween the pages of a heavy book. This would have the advantage of keeping them flat, as well as cool and dry. The book would need to be kept dry as well, as if the pages got damp they could stick together and make it impossible to get the stickers out.

The downside is that you'll need to remember which book it's in...and that the book doesn't get lost or sold.

Comment: Using a book about LEGO to store your LEGO decals in sounds perfect.

Comment: Or just put each sheet between the pages of the relevant instructions, then keep the instructions somewhere out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

We always put them in a archive folder. The quality from LEGO stickers also varies quite a bit. I'm puzzled that LEGO doesn't always seem to go for that quality materials.